# What is this series/function called? (and is it converging)?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

An interesting question popped into my mind a few hours ago, specifically.. what is the relation some number $n$ and the numbers behind it. Clearly $n$ is 1 bigger than $n-1$ and 2 bigger than $n-2$.. but what about this relation:

$$f(n) = \frac{n}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i}$$

And converging as in the sum of $f(1) + f(2) + .... f(n)$

That is... the ratio between some number and its summation of its previous numbers (.i.e $\frac{4}{1+2+3}$). It would seem to be that this already has a name but I was unable to find it on the internet and I'm curious as to its analysis.

Comment: What is the value of $f(1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ (this sum does have a closed form), you get
$$
f(n) = \frac{2}{n-1}.
$$

It may not have a name, but it does have a closed-form value.

(also, from the above we get that the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty f(n)$ diverges to $\infty$, by comparison with the harmonic series.)

Comment: As noted by peterwhy, $f(1)$ is not defined

Comment: That is why i made the sum start at 2 for the series. (But yes, i swept that under the rug.)